# Parsing an updating html using jsoup

Tags: java, html, button, jsoup

we have a problem (we are a group).

We have to use jsoup in java for an university project. We can parse Htmls with it. But the problem is that we have to parse an html which updates when you click on a button (https://www.bundestag.de/services/opendata).

[First Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9mDW.png)

[Second Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUk5n.png)

We want to access all xmls from "Wahlperiode 20". But when you click on the slide buttons the html code updates but the html url stays the same. But you have never access to all xmls in the html because the html is updating over the slide button.

Another idea was to find out how the urls of the xmls we want to access are built so that we dont have to deal with the slide buttons and only access the xml urls. But they are all built different.

So we are all desperate how to go on. I hope y'all can help us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather ironic that you are attempting to hack<sup>1</sup> out some data **from an opendata website**. There is surely an API!!

The problem is that websites aren't static resources; they have javascript, and that javascript can fetch more data in response to e.g. the user clicking a 'next page' button.

What you're doing is called 'scraping': Using automated tools to attempt to query for data via a communication channel (namely: This website) which **is definitely not meant for that**. This website is not meant to be read with software. It's meant to be read with eyeballs. If someone decides to change the design of this page and you did have a working scraper, it would then fail after the design update, for example.

You have, in broad strokes, 3 options:

### Abort this plan, this is crazy

This data is surely open, and open data tends to come with APIs; things meant to be queried by software and not by eyeballs. Go look for it, and call the german government, I'm sure they'll help you out! If they've really embraced the REST principles of design, then send an accept header that including e.g. `application/json` and `application/xml` and does not include `text/html` and see if the site just responds with the data in JSON or XML format.

I *strongly* advise you fully exhaust these options before moving on to your next options, as the next options are really bad: Lots of work and the code will be extremely fragile (any updates on the site by the bundestag website folks will break it).

### Use your browser's network inspection tools

In just about every browser there's 'dev tools'. For example, in Vivaldi, it's under the "Tools" menu and is called "Developer tools". You can also usually right click anywhere on a web page and there will be an option for 'Inspect', 'Inspector', or 'Development Tools'. Open that now, and find the 'network' tab. When you (re)load this page, you'll see **all** the resources its loading in (so, images, the HTML itself, CSS, the works). Look through it, find the interesting stuff. In this specific case, the loading of `wahlperioden.json` is of particular interest.

Let's try this out:

```
curl 'https://www.bundestag.de/static/appdata/filter/wahlperioden.json'

[{"value":"20","label":"WP 20: seit 2021"},{"value":"19","label":"WP 19: 2017 - 2021"},(rest omitted - there are a lot of these)]
```

That sounds useful, and as its JSON you can just read this stuff with a json parser. No need to use JSoup (JSoup is great as a library, but it's a library that you can use when all other options have failed, and any code written with JSoup is fragile and complicated simply because scraping sites is fragile and complicated).

Then, click on the buttons that 'load new data' and check if network traffic ensues. And so it does, when you do so, you notice a call going out. And so it is! I'm seeing this URL being loaded:

```
https://www.bundestag.de/ajax/filterlist/de/services/opendata/866354-866354?limit=10&noFilterSet=true&offset=10
```

The format is rather obvious. `offset=10` means: Start from the 10th element (as I just clicked 'next page') and `limit=10` means: NO more than 10 pages.

This html is also *incredibly basic* which is great news, as that makes it easy to scrape. Just write a for loop that keeps calling this URL, modifying the `offset=10` part (first loop: no offset. Second, offset=10, third: offset=20. Keep going until the HTML you get back is blank, then you got it all).

### For future reference: Browser emulation

Javascript can also generate entire HTML on its own; not something jsoup can ever do for you: The only way to obtain such HTML is to actually let the javascript do its work, which means you need **an entire browser**. Tools like [selenium](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-with-java-for-automated-test#:%7E:text=Selenium%20is%20the%20first%20thing,,%20C#,%20Ruby,%20Python.) will start a real browser but let you use JSoup-like constructs to retrieve information from the page (instead of what browsers usually do, which is to transmit the rendered data to your eyeballs). This tends to always work, but is *incredibly* complicated and quite slow (you're running an entire browser and really rendering the site, even if you can't see it - that's happening under the hood!).

Selenium isn't meant as a scraping tool; it's meant as a front-end testing tool. But you can use it to scrape stuff, and will have to if its generated HTML. Fortunately, you're lucky here.

Option 1 is **vastly** superior to option 2, and option 2 is **vastly** superior to option 3, at least for this case. Good luck!

[1] I'm using the definition of: Using a tool or site to accomplish something it was obviously not designed for. The sense of 'I bought half an ikea cupboard and half of an ikea bookshelf that are completely unrelated, and put them together anyway, look at how awesome this thingie is' - that sense of 'hack'. Not the sense of 'illegal'.

Comment: Thank you very much. That thing with the "network traffic" helped us a lot. Now we know how to build other urls like that for example for other "Wahlperioden". Thanks a lot :)